# MVC4 without Reflection

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-4, reflection, .net-4.5

So I have been searching for a great while, and can't for the life of me find anything concrete which explains what MVC is using reflection for. The current web hosting I'm using for testing does not support reflection, so I'm working on a way to maybe disable it.

To disable reflection I would need to know where it's used and if it's possible to disable it.

Upon publish only pages handling database-queries are throwing the security exception, which is every page except the "model"/Create

Using MVC4, .NET 4.5 and entity framework.

Any insight would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't for the life of me find anything concrete which explains what MVC is using reflection for

Reflection is used in MVC for dealing with Controller Actions:

> 99.99999% of the time we’re dealing with the default reflection based approach. So what the Controller Inspector does is to try and cast the
>   ActionDescriptor to ReflectedActionDescriptor and if that succeeds, it
>   can reflect over the action method normally to provide a lot more
>   details.

This quote, and other interesting insights can be found on [Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/08/10/writing-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-inspector.aspx/).